# Why Resharper can't tell initialization is used

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper

I am writing unit-tests while I've stumbled upon following suggestion by Resharper.

> Value assigned is not used by any execution path.

in the following code snipet.

```
[Test]
[TestCase((int)OddsRoundingModes.Floor)]
public void GetBaseOddsRoundingMode_WithCorrectRoundingMode_ShouldReturnCorrectRoundingMode(int oddsRoundingMode)
{
    // Arrange
    var oddsRoundingModeStr = oddsRoundingMode.ToString(); // <-- suggestion here
    var mock = new Mock<IConstantsStorage>();
    var oddsRoundingConfiguration = new OddsRoundingConfiguration(mock.Object);
    mock.Setup(h => h.TryGetConstant(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<int>(), out oddsRoundingModeStr))
        .Returns(true);

    // Act
    var roundingMode = oddsRoundingConfiguration.GetBaseOddsRoundingMode(0);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreNotEqual(roundingMode, OddsRoundingModes.None);
}
```

But then when I change this to be not initialized at declaration, the mock is not properly setup and test fails, because `oddsRoundingModeStr` is not initialized and the mock return it as null.

Why can't Resharper see this?

EDIT:

```
public bool TryGetConstant(string name, int siteId, out string value)
{
    value = RetrieveConstant(_constantsModel, name, siteId);

    return value != null;
}

private string RetrieveConstant<T>(IConstantsModel<T> model, string constName, int siteId)
    where T : IConstant, new()
{
    if (model.Constants.TryGetValue(constName, out List<T> values))
    {
        var constant = values.FirstOrDefault(v => v.Name == constName && v.SiteIds.Contains(siteId));
        if (constant != null)
        {
            return constant.ConstantValue;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a problem with the mock. Resharper is correct in that the value assigned is never used hence the suggestion

Comment: I think the bigger question is why your mocking fails.  from a c# perspective your code has redundancies

Comment: How so? if I dont initialize it is correctly mapped to null in the mock, same goes when I initialize it(it uses the value I supply), mock is always using the value I assign(even tho sometimes it is implicit - the case when I only declare it) to `oddsRoundingModeStr` which to me means that value that is assigned *is* used. Am I wrong?

Comment: Using `string oddsRoundingModeStr;` does not work?

Comment: @CodesInChaos , yes then value of it is null, and this null is passed to the mock which is not desired. (but resharper suggest it since to it any value supplied to `oddsRoundingModeStr` is *not* used, but it is when you do `oddsRoundingModeStr = "awesome"`

Comment: Can you post what `TryGetConstant` does? It's an `out` parameter so it shouldn't be used at all

Comment: `Setup` probably takes an `Expression<T>` and the mocking library interprets that expression in a manner that doesn't match normal C# semantics.

Comment: @Nkosi , can you elaborate I am not sure I understood, Camilo I will post it in a second.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I also think it can be something like that..

Comment: See this is why mocking is dangerous opinionated religion. https://mickyd.wordpress.com/2016/05/25/have-you-unit-tested-that-aileron-servo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following normal C# semantics the value you initialize that variable to is irrelevant, since `out` can't read the data before having assigned a new value to it. Thus the resharper notice is appropriate.

I see several ways non standard semantics could be achieved using this code:

1. `out` is a decorated `ref` at the CLR level. So low level code could treat it as equivalent to `ref`.

   ```
   void Main()
   {
       Ref r = R;
       Out o = (Out)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Out), null, r.Method);
       int i = 2;
       o(out i);
       i.Dump();
   }

   delegate void Out(out int x);
   delegate void Ref(ref int x);

   void R(ref int x)
   {
       x++;
   }
   ```
2. `Setup` takes delegate and then uses private reflection on the closure object.
3. `Setup` takes an `Expression<T>`, i.e. a syntax tree of the lambda and interprets the expression in non standard ways.

   In this context, the lambda expression is not C# code intended to be executed, but essentially a [DSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) describing how to setup the mock.

Option 3 seems the most likely

Comment: Guess by DSL you mean domain-specific language. Not heard that acronym before.

Answer (score 2):

`Setup` accepts expression tree - and Moq analyzes that expression tree to create a moq. In this case you are basically saying that Moq should create implementation of `IConstantsModel` which accepts any string, any int, returns true and returns value you provide in `oddsRoundingModeStr` as `out` parameter. So when analyzing this expression tree, Moq will extract actual value of `oddsRoundingModeStr` (which is captured and stored in a field of compiler-generated class) and indeed will use it. Resharper is just unable to realize this, so provides a warning as usual.

Small example of how `out` variable value can be extracted from expression tree:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int result = 2; // gives warning from your question
        var back = ExtractOutValue(s => int.TryParse(s, out result));           
        Debug.Assert(back == result);
    }

    static int ExtractOutValue(Expression<Action<string>> exp) {
        var call = (MethodCallExpression)exp.Body;            
        var arg = (MemberExpression) call.Arguments[1];
        return (int) ((FieldInfo)arg.Member).GetValue(((ConstantExpression)arg.Expression).Value);            
    }        
}
```